# Google DFP API ReportService is failing with no notable error message

Tags: php, google-dfp

I'm trying to pull a pretty basic report from DFP via API and the PHP library provided by Google, https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib/. I've tried both creating the query in the UI and fetching that ReportQuery from the API and running it (per https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-publishers/docs/reporting#retrieving_a_saved_reportquery) as well as creating an ad hoc query. All create the request okay, which seems to imply that the query validates okay. Other API requests I've tested work fine, including fetching a list of line items etc.

The pertinent code is as follows:

```
$statementBuilder = (new StatementBuilder())


->where('AD_UNIT_NAME like \'prebid_\'');

# Create report query.
$reportQuery = new ReportQuery();
$reportQuery->setDimensions([
  Dimension::AD_UNIT_NAME,
  Dimension::CUSTOM_CRITERIA,
  Dimension::DATE
]);
$reportQuery->setColumns([
  Column::TOTAL_INVENTORY_LEVEL_IMPRESSIONS,
  Column::TOTAL_INVENTORY_LEVEL_WITHOUT_CPD_AVERAGE_ECPM
]);
$reportQuery->setStatement($statementBuilder->toStatement());
$reportQuery->setAdUnitView(ReportQueryAdUnitView::TOP_LEVEL);
$reportQuery->setDateRangeType(DateRangeType::YESTERDAY);

# Create report job.
$reportJob = new ReportJob();
$reportJob->setReportQuery($reportQuery);

# Run report job.
$reportJob = $reportService->runReportJob($reportJob);

# Create report downloader.
$reportDownloader = new ReportDownloader($reportService, $reportJob->getId(), POLL_TIME_SECONDS);

# Wait for the report to be ready.
$reportDownloader->waitForReportToFinish();

# Change to your file location.
$filePath = sprintf('%s.csv.gz', tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(),
    'delivery-report-'));

printf("Downloading report to %s ...\n", $filePath);

# Download the report.
$reportDownloader->downloadReport('CSV_DUMP', $filePath);
```

Here's the error message I get from the API:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with message 'Cannot download report 1834923393 because it has a status of FAILED.' in ~/test/vendor/googleads/googleads-php-lib/src/Google/AdsApi/Dfp/Util/v201611/ReportDownloader.php:146
Stack trace:
#0 ~/test/vendor/googleads/googleads-php-lib/src/Google/AdsApi/Dfp/Util/v201611/ReportDownloader.php(116): Google\AdsApi\Dfp\Util\v201611\ReportDownloader->getDownloadUrl('CSV_DUMP')
#1 ~/test/dfp/get_prebid_unit_data.php(85): Google\AdsApi\Dfp\Util\v201611\ReportDownloader->downloadReport('CSV_DUMP', '/tmp/delivery-r...')
#2 {main}
  thrown in ~/test/vendor/googleads/googleads-php-lib/src/Google/AdsApi/Dfp/Util/v201611/ReportDownloader.php on line 146
```

Comment: The function comment only [states](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib/blob/5eea2f7fb65fd07f0413eb2e33bc2e7563c43078/src/Google/AdsApi/Dfp/Util/v201611/ReportDownloader.php#L112) that exception is raised when a report has failed so you might need whatever additional tools the service provides. Sadly all I could find in some Google forum is potentially the job times out :/ and no supporting docs (in their own example in the repo if the report fails it simply prints that it failed...) It seems like you may not be able to get a useful failure reason from the API as it is documented.

Answer (score 1):

I have done similar kind of report using below code. Hope it would be helpful for you.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting('E_ALL');
$date_to = isset($_GET['dateTo']) && !empty($_GET['dateTo']) ? date('Y-m-d', strtotime(trim($_GET['dateTo']))) : date('Y-m-d', strtotime('now'));
$date_from = isset($_GET['dateFrom']) && !empty($_GET['dateFrom']) ? date('Y-m-d', strtotime(trim($_GET['dateFrom']))) : date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 day'));

require_once 'Google/Api/Ads/Dfp/Lib/DfpUser.php';
//require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../../Common/ExampleUtils.php';
require_once 'Google/Api/Ads/Dfp/Util/ReportUtils.php';
require_once 'Google/Api/Ads/Dfp/Util/DateTimeUtils.php';

try {
    // Get DfpUser from credentials in "../auth.ini"
    // relative to the DfpUser.php file's directory.
    $user = new DfpUser();
    // Log SOAP XML request and response.
    // Get the ReportService.
    $reportService = $user->GetService('ReportService', 'v201405');
    // Create report job.
    $reportJob = new ReportJob();
    // Create report query.
    $reportQuery = new ReportQuery();
//    $reportQuery->dateRangeType = 'LAST_MONTH';
    $reportQuery->dateRangeType = 'CUSTOM_DATE';
//    $reportQuery->dateRangeType = 'YESTERDAY';
//    $reportQuery->dateRangeType = 'TODAY';
    $reportQuery->startDate = DateTimeUtils::GetDfpDateTime(new DateTime($date_from))->date;
    $reportQuery->endDate = DateTimeUtils::GetDfpDateTime(new DateTime($date_to))->date;

    //-- create PQL statement
//    $reportStatement = new Statement();
//    $reportStatement->query = "WHERE LINE_ITEM_TYPE = 'SPONSORSHIP'";
//    $reportQuery->statement = $reportStatement;
    //Date    Salesperson    Advertiser    Order    Line item    Line item type    Ad unit    Salesperson ID    Advertiser ID    
//
//Order ID    Line item ID    Ad unit ID    Total impressions    Total impressions    Total clicks    Total CTR
    $reportQuery->dimensions = array(
        'DATE', 'SALESPERSON_NAME', 'ADVERTISER_NAME','ORDER_NAME', 'LINE_ITEM_NAME', 'LINE_ITEM_TYPE', 'AD_UNIT_NAME'
    );

    $reportQuery->columns = array(
        'TOTAL_INVENTORY_LEVEL_IMPRESSIONS', 'TOTAL_LINE_ITEM_LEVEL_IMPRESSIONS', 'TOTAL_LINE_ITEM_LEVEL_CLICKS', 'TOTAL_LINE_ITEM_LEVEL_CTR', 'TOTAL_LINE_ITEM_LEVEL_CPM_AND_CPC_REVENUE', 'TOTAL_LINE_ITEM_LEVEL_WITH_CPD_AVERAGE_ECPM'
    );

    $reportJob->reportQuery = $reportQuery;
    // Run report job.
    $reportJob = $reportService->runReportJob($reportJob);

    do {
        printf("<p>Report with ID '%s' is running.", $reportJob->id);

        sleep(5);
        // Get report job.
        $reportJob = $reportService->getReportJob($reportJob->id);
    } while ($reportJob->reportJobStatus == 'IN_PROGRESS');

    if ($reportJob->reportJobStatus == 'FAILED') {
        printf("Report job with ID '%s' failed to finish successfully.</p>", $reportJob->id);
    } else {
        printf("Report job with ID '%s' completed successfully.</p>", $reportJob->id);
        $reportJobId = $reportJob->id;

        //-- Set the format of the report (e.g., CSV_DUMP) and download without compression so we can print it.
        $reportDownloadOptions = new ReportDownloadOptions();
//        $reportDownloadOptions->exportFormat = 'CSV_DUMP';
        $reportDownloadOptions->exportFormat = 'TSV';
        $reportDownloadOptions->useGzipCompression = false;

        //-- get download url of the report
        $downloadUrl = $reportService->getReportDownloadUrlWithOptions($reportJobId, $reportDownloadOptions);

        //-- get printed data of the report from the download url
        $report = ReportUtils::DownloadReport($downloadUrl);
        //-- now parse the report data and manage it to view/store it in Database
//        print $report.'<br><br>';die;
    }
} catch (OAuth2Exception $e) {
    ExampleUtils::CheckForOAuth2Errors($e);
//    echo "check";
} catch (ValidationException $e) {
    ExampleUtils::CheckForOAuth2Errors($e);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    print $e->getMessage() . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes sleeping on it makes all the difference. Notably, the same query, when fetched via `ReportService::getSavedQueriesByStatement`, returns the following:

```
Google\AdsApi\Dfp\v201611\SavedQuery {#52
  #id: 468197553
  #name: "Prebid KV Query"
  #reportQuery: Google\AdsApi\Dfp\v201611\ReportQuery {#49
    #dimensions: array:3 [
      0 => "AD_UNIT_NAME"
      1 => "CUSTOM_CRITERIA"
      2 => "DATE"
    ]
    #adUnitView: "TOP_LEVEL"
    #columns: array:2 [
      0 => "TOTAL_INVENTORY_LEVEL_IMPRESSIONS"
      1 => "TOTAL_INVENTORY_LEVEL_WITHOUT_CPD_AVERAGE_ECPM"
    ]
    #dimensionAttributes: null
    #customFieldIds: null
    #contentMetadataKeyHierarchyCustomTargetingKeyIds: null
    #startDate: null
    #endDate: null
    #dateRangeType: "YESTERDAY"
    #statement: Google\AdsApi\Dfp\v201611\Statement {#48
      #query: " where ad_unit_name like 'prebid_'"
      #values: null
    }
    #useSalesLocalTimeZone: false
    #includeZeroSalesRows: false
  }
  #isCompatibleWithApiVersion: true
}
```

Note the lack of `%` in the query.

However, when generating the report, `%` are required in the LIKE statement in order to properly filter.

The interesting thing here is that even pulling the saved query and generating a `ReportJob` from that without modification fails, which seems to imply that you cannot programmatically run a saved query that contains a LIKE filter?